# How do I create this dynamic htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess

This permalink/friendly url:

```
http://anything.com/ok
```

Should be serving this path/url:

```
http://anything.com/path/to/page/dir1/dir2/page.php?parameter=ok
```

This works, but this is hardcoded. need dynamic method. dir1 can be anything, dir2 can be anything, and the text after parameter= can be anything.

```
RewriteRule ^ok/{0,1}$  path/to/page/dir1/dir2/page.php?parameter=ok [QSA,L]
```

Here are bunch of things i tried without success.

```
#RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?parameter=$1
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /page\.php\?parameter=([^\&\ ]+)
#RewriteRule ^/?page\.php$ /page/%1? [L,R=301]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^path/to/page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ page.php?parameter=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^page/{0,1}$ http://%4/path/to/page/%3/%2/page.php?parameter=%1 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^$4/{0,1} http://$1/path/to/page/$2/$3/page.php?parameter=$4 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^page/{0,1}$ http://%1/path/to/page/%2/%3/page.php?parameter=%4 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^page/{0,1}$ http://$1/path/to/page/$2/$3/page.php?parameter=$4 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^$ http://$1/path/to/page/$2/$3/page.php?parameter=$4 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^$4 http://$1/path/to/page/$2/$3/page.php?parameter=$4 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^$4 http://%1/path/to/page/%2/%3/page.php?parameter=%4 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^/{0,1}$ http://$1/path/to/page/$2/$3/page.php?parameter=$4 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^/{0,1}$ http://%1/path/to/page/%2/%3/page.php?parameter=%4 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^/{0,1}$4 http://%1/path/to/page/%2/%3/page.php?parameter=%4 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^/$4 http://%1/path/to/page/%2/%3/page.php?parameter=%4 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^/$4 http://$1/path/to/page/$2/$3/page.php?parameter=$4 [QSA,L]
```

**Edit:**

This worked for a random parameter. Now I just need to know how to do random two folders in the middle of url.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ path/to/page/dir1/dir2/page.php?parameter=$1 [L]
```

Examples of random 2 folders:

```
/admin/11-blah/
/development/546-whatever/
/abc-company/46208-name-of-project/
```

Could be anything as those 2 directory names. No special characters except dash though. alphanumeric and dash.

**Edit 2:**

Am i to understand that the friendly rewrite has to contain all the dynamic elements of the full dirty url?

I got this to work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ path/to/page/$1/$2/page.php?parameter=$3 [L]
```

which means the clean url will look like this:

```
http://anything.com/admin/11-blah/ok
```

but there's no way to make it look like this?:

```
http://anything.com/ok
```

Comment: So... based on exactly what should be _dir1_ and/or _dir2_ dynamic?

Comment: those 2 directories can be random. first one is a company name, second one is project name, and the thing after parameter specifies the user visiting the page. all 3 things are random.

Comment: many different companies, many different projects for each company, and tons of users for each project.

Comment: Your question is laid as if you want from users visiting `http://anything.com/ok` to be ***redirected to*** `http://anything.com/path/to/page/<dir1>/<dir2>/page.php?parameter=ok` (which does not make sense, because you would need to get your `<dir1>` and `<dir2>` somewhere)... So I guess you want it the other way? It's really not clear from your question.

Comment: the short url should stick in browser address bar, but should be serving files from long url which are physically there.  the whole path is physically there. all the folders leading up to the parameter.  need to somehow make short url or permalink or whatever the terminology is.  there are thousands upon thousands of combinations or url's and the right way is not to create thousands of lines in htaccess, so asking for better way.

Comment: dir1 is company and dir2 is project and parameter is the users visiting. 
 the amount of companies and projects are not so large. it's the users that are a lot.  company1 project 1 might have 10000 users.  company1 project 2 might have 5000 users. and so on. then same for company 2 and 3, etc. so need a universal rule of some sort to handle all those combinations of urls (short urls for all the long urls).

Comment: So... do you want your users to visit `http://anything.com/ok` *(which will be in their address bar)* and the server would then *(opaquely, without the user's knowledge)* serve pages from `http://anything.com/path/to/page/<dir1>/<dir2>/page.php?parameter=ok`? If so, do you realize that there is no information in the `http://anything.com/ok` URL that the server can use to determine what *specific* `<dir1>` and `<dir2>` to use? You still have not specified **how exactly these two should be determined by the server.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169376/discussion-between-leoarce-and-smuuf).